# Unexpected Identifier error, when tried to embed html inside JS Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was able to generate a listview using material desgin of bootstrap statically. But when I tried to build that dynamically using for-loop and jquery append I can't seem to get the result. The error thrown is Unexpected identifier
The code of index.html is

```
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/material.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container"> </div>

            <div class="list-group-item">

            <div class ="app">
              </div>

             </div> 

    </body>
</html>
```

In the above index.html, I am trying to append the list view to the element app. So here is my following js code

```
var names = ["Larry", "Jobs", "Buffet", "Gates"];
var phones = ["90000 00000", "911111 000000", "90000 11111", "80000 80808"];
for(var i=0;i<5;i++){

    add(names[i], phones[i]);

}


function add(name, phone){

   var listItem = "<div class="row-picture">"+
            "<img class="circle" src="http://"bla">"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class="row-content">"+
            "<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">"+name+"</h4>"+
            "<p class="list-group-item-text">+phone+</p>"+
        "</div>" +
        "</div>" +
     "<div class="list-group-separator"></div>"+


}
$('.app').append(listItem);
}
```

is this something related to strings escaping? I am getting error at line 12

Comment: _is this something related to strings escaping?_ Yes, it is. Every single doublequote inside double quote **must** be escaped, same rule with single quotes inside single quotes, while you can use single quotes inside double quotes and double quotes inside single quotes. (Also, there are many other syntax error in your code, but you should find them out easily)

Comment: You also have a  trailing `+`, color coding in the code block above shows the issue with the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because, your `app.js` uses jQuery, you'll need to include jQuery before app.js.

Load the jQuery library before app.js by changing their sequence.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

You need to learn to `escape` quotes. Use single quotes `'` outside string and `"` inside or vice-versa.

```
var listItem = '<div class="row-picture">' +
    '<img class="circle" src="http://"bla">' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="row-content">' +
    '<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">' + name + '</h4>' +
    '<p class="list-group-item-text">' + phone + '</p>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="list-group-separator"></div>'; // Use ; here instead of +

$('.app').append(listItem);
```

Comment: `'<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">"+name+"</h4>'` + should be  `'<h4 class="list-group-item-heading">"'+name+'"</h4>' +` :) (same with the phone line below it)

Answer (score 1):

The variable **listItem** is local you mention and use it in outside of the function Move the append method inside the function

```
function add(name, phone){
   var listItem = "<div class='row-picture'>" +
                     "<img class='circle' src='http://'bla'>" +
                  "</div>" +
                  "<div class='row-content'>"+
                    "<h4 class='list-group-item-heading'>"+ name +"</h4>" +
                    "<p class='list-group-item-text'>"+ phone +"</p>" +
                  "</div>" +
                  "<div class='list-group-separator'></div>";
     $('.app').append(listItem);
}
```

Comment: @gates: That means that you didn't include jQuery.